# How do you clear a plain HTML form after onsubmit?

Tags: javascript, html

After the onsubmit event has fired and the form has been submitted (via an action="mailto:yournamehere@somebox.com") , is there a way to then clear the form, close the window or what? Is there a post submit that I can hook into via JavaScript. This must be a client side only solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function submit_form() {
document.formu1.submit();
document.formu1.reset(); 
}
```

```html
<form name="formu1" action="action-page" method="POST" target="_blank" />
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br /><br />
Pass: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="submit_form();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 21):

A quick and easy solution:

```
<form action="mailto:email@email.com"
    onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
```

Comment: My code looks like this:
<form action="mailto:you@here.com" method="post" name="volunteer" id="volunteer" onsubmit="this.submit();this.reset();return false;" enctype="text/plain">

This gives me a JavaScript error saying that the object dosen't support this property or method. I'm looking for another smoking gun to cause thi issue. When the extra onsubmit code is removed, everything is ok. So I'm a little stumped.

Comment: I will in a few, dragged off to another prokject but will come back to edit the question a bit

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event.

You could hack it with something along the lines of:

```
// Begin anonymous wrapper function to limit the scope of variables
// and avoid namespace collisions.
(function () {
  // Get a quick reference to the form. 
  var f = document.forms.myForm;
  // Define a submit handler that won't actually
  // do anything until after the form has "submitted"
  f.onsubmit = function () {
    setTimeout(f.reset, 1000);
  }
}());
```

… but action="mailto:…" is poorly supported, so you should use a real form handler instead of trying to hack around the [limitations of mailto:](http://www.isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how that works. Once the form has been submited. Nothing happens. I'm dropping the reference to the form along the way somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put:

```
document.getElementById("myform").reset();
```

in your `onSubmit()` handler function.

Comment: This way it's going to reset the form before it is submitted. It needs to be done after `.submit()` action.